# Are those 2 problabilities equal?

Tags: probability

Need that answer to some generator I am making.

Are the chance of getting 1 and 2, the same on both games?

Game 1

1. Roll a dice with 100 sides (1 to 100)
2. If you get 30 or less you get 1 point
3. If you get more than 30 you get 2 points.

Game 2

1. Flip coin
2. If tail
   2.1. Roll a dice with 100 sides (1 to 100)
   2.2. If you get 30 or less you get 1 point if not go back to 1.
3. If Heads
   3.1. Roll a dice with 100 sides (1 to 100)
   3.2. If you get 70 or less you get 2 point if not go back to 1.

PS: the 30, 70 and 100 (so, 30+70) are just arbritrary numbers to show the examples.

Comment: Where do you struggle with computing the probabilities of getting 1 and 2 in each game?

Comment: I just want to know if I can use the second style selecting a thing at random (or in the case of example, getting points) instead of the first one and have the same result.  
I am currently using the second method (would have to change alot of code to use first one), assuming they are equivalent, but if they arent equivalent, will have to change my code to use the first.

Answer (score 1):

You can summarize Game 2 by saying that on each turn, you score 1 15% of the time, score 2 35%, and replay 50%. While it is possible for the game to go on forever without a score, that will happen with probability 0, and the game will end with a score of 1 30% of the time and a score of 2 70% of the time, which is (essentially) equivalent to Game 1.

To see the computation in detail, add up the probabilities of scoring 1 on first turn, on second turn, etc to find the probability of ending with a score of 1:

$0.15 + (1/2)0.15 + (1/4)0.15 + ... = 0.15(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ...) = 0.15(2) = 0.3$

and the sum for probability of scoring 2 is the same with 0.7 in place of 0.3.